# How to fetch data from firebase :

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch dates field but the code below is not doing so.  the Toast is showing null (value of  String date).

[image: this is my database]

public String date;

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    DatabaseReference rootRef , demoRef;
    //database reference pointing to root of database
    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //database reference pointing to demo node
    demoRef = rootRef.child("dates");

    demoRef.child("date").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            date = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(getContext() , date , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: the toast is showing null because it is asynchronous

Comment: even Log.d() is giving the same result null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the toast inside onDataChange:

```
 demoRef.child("date").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        date = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

Toast.makeText(getContext() , date , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Since `onDataChange` is asynchronous,it moves on to another task before it finishes retrieving data , then you need to add the toast inside the method.

Comment: now its showing this error..................java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293294/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-content-context-getresources-on-a-n/39293446

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
```

For further details check firebase documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write