# I'm getting 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'

Tags: android

I have tried many ways to resolve the problem but unfortunately failed to find a solution. This is my main activity from where I am calling to pager adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);


    sliderAdapter = new _SliderAdapter(Activity.this);

    intro_view_pager = findViewById(R.id.intro_view_pager);
    intro_view_pager.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);





}
```

This is my pager adapter class. I am trying to get resource string but context is always getting null:

```
    static Context mcontext;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public Wazu_SliderAdapter(Context context){
        this.mcontext =context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slide_headings.length;
    }


    public String[] slide_headings={



      mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.headng1),

    };


    public String[] slide_description={

            mcontext.getString(R.string.string1),

    };

    public int[] slide_Images={

            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,

    };





    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view==(RelativeLayout)object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(mcontext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_layout,container,false);

        ImageView imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.intro_image);
        TextView heading_text=view.findViewById(R.id.intro_heading_textView);
        TextView description=view.findViewById(R.id.intro_textView_description);

        imageView.setImageResource(slide_Images[position]);
        heading_text.setText(slide_headings[position]);
        description.setText(slide_description[position]);

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293294/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-content-context-getresources-on-a-n)

Comment: Avoid to make static context **`static Context mcontext`**

Comment: thanks kahled Lela but this is not solved my solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this lines in method **`instantiateItem`**

```
layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(mcontext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_layout,container,false);
```

use like this,

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slider_layout,container,false);
```

Issue is `context` passed is getting **null**.

& for `getCount` method use like :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.headng1).length;
}
```

You're using context at declaration time here

```
public String[] slide_description={
    mcontext.getString(R.string.string1),
};
```

That's why it's **null**.

Comment: hy dear Jeel Vankhede thanks for your help please help me little more...

Comment: i want to know how i get resource  string in this method because i m still getting erorr                                                                                        public String[] slide_description={
    mcontext.getString(R.string.string1),                                               
};

Comment: can you explain me more what you're doing with that `slide_description`?

Comment: slide description is also string and i am using this strings in all pages of viewpager to explain something